# How to get sum of total values in pivot_wider instead of a list?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
    data <- data.frame(row_id = 0:19, Prediction = c(4.20631885375613, 
0.677197140556434, 0.889543113836738, 37.8093227242093, 105.860956599905, 
17.2609337360412, 0.41323004743284, 6.94073422786919, 2.08635131353358, 
72.7283615643886, 12.2655072861912, 3.77794122863612, 4.50660941933039, 
0.877724474431314, 2.86251575017408, 31.3229122662926, 2.32802608836313, 
0.616664152263578, 2.00202294742939, 1.39842036444256), Explanation.1.Strength = c("", 
"", "", "", "+++", "", "--", "", "", "+++", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", ""), Explanation.1.Feature = c("", "", "", "", 
"is_overnight_shipping", "", "number_items", "", "", "is_overnight_shipping", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Explanation.1.Value = c("", 
"", "", "", "'1'", "", "'1'", "", "", "'1'", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", ""))
```

Code I used:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Explanation.1.Strength = if_else(Explanation.1.Strength == "", "unknown", Explanation.1.Strength)) %>%
  pivot_wider(Explanation.1.Feature, names_from = Explanation.1.Strength, values_from = Explanation.1.Value)
```

I'm getting output with lists, how to get the sum of values instead of a list output?

Comment: This gives me `Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.`, which states that your expansion is not 1-for-1. Perhaps you can include your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `values_fn` in `pivot_wider` to return the `sum`.  If these are `NA` elements, use `sum(!is.na(.))` or if it is just blank (`""`), then `sum(nzchar(.))`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
mutate(Explanation.1.Strength = if_else(Explanation.1.Strength == "", "unknown",
  Explanation.1.Strength)) %>%
  pivot_wider(Explanation.1.Feature, names_from = Explanation.1.Strength, values_from = Explanation.1.Value,
      values_fn = list(Explanation.1.Value = ~sum(!is.na(.), na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Explanation.1.Feature   unknown `+++`  `--`
#  <chr>                     <int> <int> <int>
#1 ""                           17    NA    NA
#2 "is_overnight_shipping"      NA     2    NA
#3 "number_items"               NA    NA     1
```

Comment: Error in .Primitive("sum")(..., na.rm = na.rm) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: @RohanKataria The `str` of your data shows it is a character column.  I thought it is a numeric one when you want the `sum`

Comment: I want the sum of counts for "Explanation Values"

Comment: Perfect! Worked